# Getting notifications from a deleted app

Tags: settings, applications, appcenter, notifications, notification-badge

Hello everyone im running elementary OS 5.0 Juno Linux 4.15.0-47-generic, GTK+ 3.22.30

I downloaded about a week [Badger](https://github.com/elfenware/badger) 1.3.0. I uninstalled the app but I still get notifications from the app as if the app is still installed. The only difference is that now its labelled as "Others"

I can't find a way to stop the notifications for this app

Comment: Please execute `apt list --installed` and confirm if you see that package installed in your system.